# htlatex/tex4ht without hyperlinks in HTML file?

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

How do I disable the creation of hyperlink with `tex4ht`? They are unnecessary when preparing a paper for publication in one of those ... (insert any attribute you find appropriate) journals that require Word.

I have removed the `hyperref` package, no luck. It doesn't appear in the logs, I have checked that. My command line is:

```
htlatex paper.tex "word" 'symbol/!' "-cvalidate"
```

The tables, figures and bibliography entries are accessible via hyperlinks. How do I get rid of the anchors and of the links?

**EDIT**: The document in question uses the `natbib` package. Adding

```
\Configure{cite}{}{}{}{}
\Configure{bibitem}{}{}
```

to a custom `.cfg` file didn't change anything.

Comment: perhaps you removed hyperlink & cite commands but not *all* the auxiliary files? I'd try again, no hyperref, no autoref & a clean directory ...

Comment: @prettygully: Nope, no luck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the following in your `.cfg` file below `\Preamble` above `\begin{document}`:

```
\renewcommand{\Link}[3][]{}
\renewcommand{\EndLink}{}
```

Crude and effective.

Answer (score 3):

Generate html that is compatible with word

1. htlatex  'html,word' 'symbol/!' (note single quotes are needed in Unix shells to prevent ! being expanded)
2. Open  in Microsoft Word. Change to Print Layout
3. Select all text (or specific regions as you need)
4. Cmd-shift F9 (Mac) or Ctrl-shift F9 (PC) removes the field codes and replaces them with the text equivalent
5. Use advanced search for formatting "superscript + underline" and replace with "superscript + no underline"
6. (Optional) Use advanced search and replace to change colour of superscripts and to increase  point size
7. Save as Word document

I also find that some manual font size corrections are needed for inline (simple) math symbols

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called `hidden-ref`.
This generates an openoffice file (test.odt which you can then export to word) where all the bib entry links are gone:
`htlatex test.tex "xhtml,ooffice,hidden-ref" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-coo -cvalidate"`

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Ubuntu, current TeXlive). With these options, there is supposed to exist a file `hidden-ref.cfg`, but `locate` tells me there is none. I'm just fetching the most recent updates of TeXlive to see if things change. -- How did you work out this solution? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Update: I have found [this post](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-07/msg00515.html) by Eitan Gurari. I guess I will have to look out for the file on the web somewhere...

Comment: @user946850 : I found an older shell script I used previously - as far as I remember, I did follow instructions I found on the web somewhere. I did check a small example this arvo - it did work (I did not go further than openoffice though); I am on ubuntu 10.04, texlive 2011 (up to date) - and can't find such .cfg either.

Comment: After some digging I found that hidden-ref is supported in `ooffice` only and only hides the links, not removes them. I need `word` for my use case. Thanks anyway.